# Bit manipulation, return 0 if x != 0, or nonzero otherwise

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I am writing a function `is_zero` that is supposed to return `0` if `x != 0`, or nonzero otherwise.  I am not allowed to use any constants.  For example, `x == 0` is not allowed. (the == operator is not allowed either)

The only operators I am allowed to use are `=`, `~`, `^`, `*` (dereferencing), `&`, `|`, `<<`, `>>` and `+`.

The way I have the function written now is it will return `0` if `x != 0`, but it still returns `0` even when `x == 0`, which is it not supposed to do.  I have attempted all sorts of combinations, but this homework question appears impossible given the constraints.  I am posting here as a last ditch effort.

Can anybody how me how I can get my code to return something other than `0` when `x == 0`, while still returning `0` when `x != 0`?

```
int is_zero(int x) {
    return (x ^ x);
}
```

Comment: Write down the bit-pattern of some simple non-zero value, and experiment with that. For example, if you have a non-zero value, what happens if you use bitwise and with itself? What happens if you have bitwise and with the opposite (using the `~` operator) of itself? What happens when you use the `~` on a non-zero value? On a value that's zero?

Comment: `return (x ^ ~x);` will work.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, that solution does not seem to work.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `x ^ ~x` is always `(unsigned)(-1)`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I've tried all sorts of possible combinations, and nothing I come up with works.  Unless I am missing something obvious, I believe this is impossible.

Comment: I missed the 2nd part of the criteria, so no, what won't work.

Comment: Is `>>` not allowed?

Comment: `>>` is allowed.  I have updated the post.

Comment: if you do not want to use ==, why not directly use a condition like `if (x) { return 0;} else { return 1;}`

Comment: `if` / `else` is not allowed unfortunately.  Only bitwise operators.  We also cannot use any constants, such as `0`.

Comment: Why wouldn't `~(x|y)` work?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, what is the `y` variable?

Comment: `not allowed to use any constants` so operations like `x >> 7` are not allowed?

Comment: Correct operations like `x >> 7` are not allowed.

Comment: Any compliment. In looking at DeMorgan's laws and the various truth-tables for their operations , you will have `x=0, y=0` (zero case), then `x=1, y=0`, then `x=0, y=1` and finally `x=1, y=1`. In the case of `0,0` `~(x|y)` is non-zero, zero everywhere else.

Comment: Are you assuming a specific word size, or should this work for any word size?

Comment: @TomKarzes, should work with any size.

Comment: `* (dereferencing)` - not multiplication?

Comment: @OmarN do you have a link to the actual question? Usually these sorts of bitwise trick solutions depend crucially on the size of `int`, so I'm surprised if it's supposed to be word-size independent.

Comment: Pretty tired of "How do I do this without using A,B,C?"  "(answer posted using D)"  "Oh, can't use D either"  "(answer posted using E)"  "Oh, can't use E either" etc...

Comment: It turns out there *is* a general solution to this, which I have just posted.  It does not depend on the word size, or even on two's complement arithmetic.

Comment: Nevermind I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Can't really understand the down-votes. The question is properly formulated, the OP answers to clarification questions and the whole thing is a nice brain-teaser (addmittedly, entirely un-practical and maybe useless knowledge, though.) Note you can't downvote the OP's professor here ;)

Comment: Thanks @tofro!  I never understood the downvotes here either since the question is perfectly valid and formulated.  Some people just like downvoting for no reason.  Wish we could get them off this site!

Comment: Thanks, although I wasn't trying to get you to accept a solution that you didn't consider best.  I just thought I had answered the wrong question.  It also looks like I just got a down-vote from someone?  Wondering if it was an accident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is a general solution, which does not depend on word size, or even on two's complement arithmetic.  Here it is:

```
int is_zero(int x)
{
    unsigned    y   = x;
    unsigned    c0  = y^y;
    unsigned    c1  = ~(~c0 + ~c0);
    unsigned    c1h = ~c0 ^ (~c0 >> c1);
    unsigned    y2  = y + ~c0;
    unsigned    t1  = y ^ y2;
    unsigned    t2  = t1 & y2;
    unsigned    s   = t2 & c1h;
    int         r   = s >> c1;

    return r;
}
```

Note that everything is done in unsigned, which is necessary to avoid overflow issues, and also to force the right shift to zero-fill.  I left the argument and return value as signed ints, with the first and last assignments simply changing the signed/unsigned behavior (the final shift is only present to avoid overflow - see the comment below).

The solution is actually pretty straightforward.  As has been noted, constant generation is trivial.  Zero is obtained by xor-ing something with itself.  All 1's is the bitwise complement of that.  One is all 1's xor'd with all 1's shifted left one.

So far this is all pretty trivial.  The tricky part is to get it to work regardless of word size.  To do this, it constructs a value whose high-order bit is 0 if x is non-zero, and 1 if x is zero.  It then masks this with a constant which is a single 1 in the high-order bit position, which is constructed from all 1's xor'd with all 1's shifted right 1.  The shift is guaranteed to zero-fill (rather than sign-extend) since the value is unsigned.

Note that `s` is either zero or a one in the high-order bit position.  The final return value, `r`, shifts `s` right by one in order to avoid overflow when assigning back to a signed integer.  This fix was suggested by Paul Hankin.  This makes the final return value either zero or else zero followed by one followed by all zeros.

If you want to avoid the implicit conversions between signed and unsigned at the beginning and end of the function, you can use a union to alias the values:

```
int is_zero(int x)
{
    union {int s; unsigned u;} su;
    su.s = x;
    unsigned    y   = su.u;
    unsigned    c0  = y^y;
    unsigned    c1  = ~(~c0 + ~c0);
    unsigned    c1h = ~c0 ^ (~c0 >> c1);
    unsigned    y2  = y + ~c0;
    unsigned    t1  = y ^ y2;
    unsigned    t2  = t1 & y2;
    unsigned    s   = t2 & c1h;
    su.u = s;
    int         r = su.s;

    return r;
}
```

In this case, the final shift of `s` is unnecessary, and the return value is either zero or else one followed by all zeros.  Note that the C90 standard doesn't allow mixed code and declarations, so if that's an issue, you would have to separate the declarations from the assignments, but the net result would be the same.

Comment: If conversion to other types is allowed, then it really is trivial: `return ~(bool)x;`

Comment: @Paul It's not a representation change. It's just using unsigned operators.  It could use pointers to get an unsigned variable. The problem seems to allow for this. It could also use unions, if allowed. Arguably the function should take and return an unsigned anyway.  It wasn't clear if the signed argument and return value were actually required.

Comment: The last line should be: `int r = s >> c1;` -- as written it's undefined behavior.

Comment: @Paul Hm, I could be wrong about this.  I don't have a reference that I can check.  You're right though, right-shifting by one would guarantee that it's safe.

Comment: `s` isn't representable as an `int`, so it's definitely UB to cast it. You should just update your code -- you don't need to give credit in the answer for the fix.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe it's possible to solve if you want the code to work without assuming a certain size of `int` and representation. But this works for 32-bit ints and two's complement representation:

```
int is_zero(int x) {
    int zero = (x^x);
    int one = ~(~zero + ~zero);
    int five = one + one + one + one + one;
    int thirtyone = (one << five) + ~zero;
    return ~((x >> thirtyone) | ((~x + one) >> thirtyone));
}
```

It uses multiple assignments to construct the constants, but the code could be folded into a single expression if necessary.

### How it works

`(x >> thirtyone)` is -1 if `x` is negative and 0 otherwise.
Similarly, `(~x + one) >> thirtyone` is -1 if `x` is positive, and 0 otherwise.

The bitwise `or` of these two expressions is `0` if `x` is zero, and `-1` otherwise. A bitwise `~` then gives -1 if `x` is zero, and 0 otherwise.

## (Almost) word-size independent solution

It's not perfectly word-size independent, but one can extend the solution above to work for 16, 32 and 64 bit ints (although still depending on two's complement representation). The code is careful to not shift more than 15 bits at a time (otherwise the result is undefined behavior if `int` is 16 bits):

```
int is_zero(int x) {
    int zero = (x^x);
    int one = ~(~zero + ~zero);
    int four = one + one + one + one;
    int k15 = (one << four) + ~zero;
    return ~((x >> k15 >> k15 >> k15 >> k15 >> k15) |
             ((~x + one) >> k15 >> k15 >> k15 >> k15 >> k15));
}
```

Comment: See the comments.  I asked if a specific word size could be assumed, and the answer was no, it must work with any word size.  Otherwise it's easy, as you discovered.

Comment: @TomKarzes I think this is going to be as good as answer as is possible -- I believe it's impossible to do if you don't assume a fixed word size. I'll modify my answer to include this.

Comment: You may be right - I'm not sure yet.  Generating any fixed constant is trivial, and if you know the word size, it makes for an easy solution.  Without knowing the word size, it's much tougher if in fact it's even possible.

Comment: @TomKarzes It didn't seem so trivial and easy to the various people who posted incorrect solutions, or (like yourself) no solution at all.

Comment: I knew how to solve it with a fixed word size, as I said.  I didn't write it up because I wasn't sure if a fixed word size could be assumed.  Your solution was obvious to me.  I'm still working on a general solution, which I now think may be possible.  That's the real challenge.  So far no one has posted a solution that meets OP's stated goal.

Comment: I cracked it.  See my posted solution.

Comment: Since you got me thinking about overflow, I was wondering what happens in your solution if `x` is `MIN_INT` (assuming two's complement).  In that case, `~x` is `MAX_INT`, so (`~x + one`) is `MAX_INT + 1`.  Isn't that an overflow condition, with undefined behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Note this builds on @Paul Hankin's answer on how to get to 0 and 1 as constants. (If you were allowed to use the "/" operator, 1 would be easier to obtain by (`x/x`). So, one theoretical way of doing it may be

- Obtain the constants 0 and 1 as in @PaulHankin 's answer (nice, BTW)
- using these "constants", shift x by all possible bit positions left, ORing the results (shifts any "1" in the original to any possible bit position, giving -1 (0xffff) in the end. As we don't seem to know the size of an integer, do it 64 or 128 (or 1000) times or even more often to be on the safe side and cover all reasonable `int` sizes. (That line might become a bit long...) Adding too many shifts will not hurt.

`x = x | x << one | x << one+one | x << one + one + one ....`

This might actually end up in UB, if the shift is more than the actual word width, but is fixed by writing (Thanks to @PaulHankin's comment)

`x = x | x << one | x << one << one | x << one << one << one ....`

- if x was originally 0, you'll have a 0 in x now. If it had any bit set (i.e was different from 0), you have any bit above the originally set one set.
- do the same thing shifting right, you'll have 0xffff (or whatever your word size would be) or 0, then
- XOR the result from above with -1 (obtained as a constant from `0 - 1`) - This will result in -1 for original 0, 0 for original anything else, return that, at last.

I am pretty sure I don't want to write that program. And it might easily go beyond any reasonable line length of your compiler.

Comment: This still isn't really general.  It just says it will work for any "reasonable" bound on the word size.

Comment: At some point `x << one + one + ... + one` will cause undefined behavior (a shift left by the width of the integer or more is undefined behavior). But you can fix that by writing `x << one << one << ... << one` instead.

Comment: @TomKarzes It also uses an unreasonable amount of shifts. The more you insert, the more it would cover "unreasonable" word sizes. But agreed, I like your solution more.

Comment: But the whole thing is an unreasonable attempt anyhow ;)

Answer (score 0):

Small optimization of @TomKarzes answer:

```
int is_zero2(int x)
{
    unsigned y   = x;             // use (unsigned) x
    unsigned c0  = y ^ y;         // = 0
    unsigned c1  = ~(~c0 + ~c0);  // = 1
    unsigned c1h = ~(~c0 >> c1);  // = mask for sign bit
    unsigned t2  = ~(y | -y);     // mask for bits below (not including) lowest bit set
    unsigned s   = t2 & c1h;      // sign bit: 0 = (x != 0), 1 = (x == 0)
    int      r   = s >> c1;       // prevent overflow
    return r;
}
```