# Check if integer is 0 with two restricted operations

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am trying to write a function `isZero(int x)` that returns 1 if x is 0, and returns 0 otherwise.  How can I only do this with two of the following operators?

`!` `~` `&` `^` `|` `+` `<<` `>>`

Comment: ...but why not just `x == 0`? Technically `!x` works as well, but `!` isn't a bitwise operation.

Comment: the restriction is that I have to use bitwise operations.  no == or !=, ifs, or whiles.

Comment: It cannot be done with purely bitwise operators. A purely bitwise operation is one in which each bit in the result is a function of only the bits in the same position in the operands, not of neighboring or other bits. Therefore, a 1 in the low bit of a return value cannot be a function of anything other than low bits in the input. Presumably, you want to do this with more than just purely bitwise operands. So we need a list of operations that are allowed.

Comment: Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36856056/bit-manipulation-return-0-if-x-0-or-nonzero-otherwise

Comment: `Operations allowed: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>` So just `!x`

Comment: `bool isZero(int x) { return !x ^ 0; }` if one must use 2 operators.

Comment: @ chux - Reinstate Monica it works! thanks.

Comment: `!` and `+` are not bitwise operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `!!!x`?

Look at following diagram for values zero and different than zero:

```
      x == 0 | x <> 0
      -------+-------
!x         1 |      0
!!x        0 |      1
!!!x       1 |      0
```

Isn't that what you want?

Comment: That's 3 operators, not 2 operators..

Comment: @Brendan: no, it's just one :-)

Comment: One is also not two.

Answer (score 0):

Several ways, among them `!+x`, `+!x`, `!x | 0`, `!x << 0`. These all assume you meant "use two different operators from the given list exactly once".